# I can't create EFI partition (ESP) using Diskpart, on the hard drive

Tags: hard-drive, boot, cmd.exe, diskpart

So I'm about to do one of my project: "*Windows To Go without WinToGo*" (don't care about it). The real problem is when I tried to create ESP to boot, it said:No usable free extent could be found. It may be that there is insufficient free space to create a partition at the specified size and offset. Specify different size and offset values or don't specify either to create the maximum sized partition. It may be that the disk is partitioned using the MBR disk partitioning format and the disk contains either 4 primary partitions, (no more partitions may be created), or 3 primary partitions and one extended partition, (only logical drives may be created).
Then I tried to create it on my hard drive to copy it (EaseUS ParMgr PE Edition have ESP Explore feature). It's the same message. The research just talk about when create EFI partition on removable devices on most articles, not hard drive. The hard drive I'm trying to create with it is a main drive that have my  main *Windows*. Why I can't manually copy Boot files instead of using Command Shell? Just I can't find any *Boot* folder! And where the ESP to copy to?
I hope who find it is possible or not, quick!

Answer (score 1):

"UEFI BIOS" + "EFI Boot Configuration" +  "GPT Partition Type" + "EFI Boot Partition" is the set that fits together. — If there is no strong reason (i.e. no UEFI BIOS mode available) then use it this way.

If you insist to use the MBR partition scheme, you do not need an EFI partition and have to use the BIOS Legacy mode. Also you will need to flag the partition with the boot manager as "bootable".

Perhaps you might want to read ["Boot to UEFI Mode or legacy BIOS mode" at Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/boot-to-uefi-mode-or-legacy-bios-mode?view=windows-11).

If you use MBR, the maximum count of possible "Primary Partitions" is 4.
You can replace one primary partition by an "Extended Partition" that can contain much more partitions (Logical Partitions). This cannot be circumvented as the space in the MBR's partition table is limited.

Perhaps you might want to migrate the MBR to GPT. Using [MBR2GPT.EXE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/mbr-to-gpt) this is possible without moving the data. *(But you always should have a backup!)*

Preferably you do a clean install of Windows on the final GPT partition as successive failures might arise due to the change of the partitioning scheme and the connected implications.

---

> The research just talk about when create EFI partition on removable devices on most articles, not hard drive.

The Boot media is not of interest. The UEFI BIOS just has to know how to find and handle it.

On a media using the GPT parititon scheme the partition type "EFI Boot Partition" itself is defined to be bootable. This partition usually is formated as FAT32, but this is not a fix requirement. The UEFI system just has to be able to read the used format.

The data on the EFI partition is just a regular, well defined file and folder structure. There is no "hidden magic" with it, so it can be build by just copying the required structure to the the partition.
But within Windows you will not see this partition as a regular user should not do any manipulations on it. Same intent is to the rescue partition. You also will not see it as regular user.

You can assign the ESP a drive letter and access it by starting a command shell *with administrator privileges* and issue

```
mountvol <drive>: /s
```

Additionally to properly setting up the ESP you will also have to setup the "EFI Boot Configuration" that is stored in the NVRAM of the computer's motherboard. Aside to some auto-detection the UEFI system will access these data to know what to do and how to boot which operating system.

Perhaps you want to read about the Microsoft tools [bcdboot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/bcdboot) and [bcdedit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/bcdedit) or get an ["Overview of Boot Options in EFI"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/overview-of-boot-options-in-efi).

Comment: Asking for multiple themes violates the rules of Superuser.com. You should focus on one answerable question. — So split off your additional questions like *"Why I can't manually copy Boot files instead of using Command Shell? Just I can't find any Boot folder! And where the ESP to copy to?"* and make them more precise. We also love to see the efforts you already have done (some code or other details) so we can save time by directly answering your question.